# jQuery and AJAX, 'post' data to .PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I can't seem to get the 123.php return information to use in the html document where I use jQuery-AJAX-thing (to change the content of div named div1).
Im pretty new to JavaScript, PHP and html; but tried some tutorials now and can't seem to make em fit my needs so would really appriciate some help.

Here is my 123.html that should use AJAX-jQuery thing to call my 123.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/123.php",
        data:{id:"3", name:"John Doe"},
        success:function(response){
            alert('ok-'+data+'-'+respText+'-'+xhr);
            $("#div1").html(respText);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }                  
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
```

along with the 123.php

```
<?php 
    $my_id = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
    $my_name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);

    $file = '123.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append to the file
    $current .= 'time:' . time() . ',id:' . $my_id . ',name:' . $my_name . "\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    echo 'received following: id: ' . $my_id . ' and name: ' . $my_name;
?>
```

The 123.txt was just to see if the php file responded, and it does, but only when I pass 
    /123.php?id=7&name=Jane%20Doe
Elsewhere using the 'post' method, no response (gets errors from the JavaScript)

So I guess it's the structure of AJAX/jQuery;
for the attempt listed above, I get the error in JavaScript-console "Uncaught error: reference not defined"

and when I use the following 123.html instead (replacing the other 123.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").post("/123.php",{id:"3",name:"John Doe"},function(data,status){alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">Text that should be changed</div>
<button>Press me, I'm a button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function", I tried to look it up and some people wrote that it could be solved inserting

```
(function ($) {
   $(document);
}(jQuery));
```

However it did not (inserted it in the very top, just below the script-start-tag )

I can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong, and I really appriciate any help and directions as for where to look.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please narrow it down. `Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function` is a Javascript error. You try to call a function that doesn't exist. The important thing is to narrow it down to the line that causes this error. The entire PHP stuff is hardly important.

Comment: If you look in the debugger tools for your browser does it say which line it is erroring out on?

Comment: Seems like following might help:

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was just stuck for a few days. Guess I should have researched better towards jQuery and it's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php is not returning JSON or XML therefore you cannot get data. Replace this

```
success:function(response){
            alert('ok-'+data+'-'+respText+'-'+xhr);
            $("#div1").html(respText);
        },
```

with this

```
success:function(response){
            alert('ok-'+response);
            $("#div1").html(response);
        },
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I guess I need my eyes trained better for this language :)
Worked spot on

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess I still have much to learn (xml, JSON ... )
got it to function as I wanted thanks to you

Thanks alot - now the programming begins :)